# Redirect to page after true result

Tags: php

Hello thanks for your time.
I have a file called get getresult.php it checks for username and password on mysql server for users that login.

I just it to redirect to a page index.php if login is successful.
Thanks for any help the can be provided.

```
<?php
// version 1.1
if (isset($_POST['password'])) // if the password is set then the  form has been submitted on login.php page
{
 include("config.php");
 $username =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
 $qstr = "SELECT * from members where username ='$username' and password ='$password'";

 $result = mysql_query($qstr);
 if (mysql_num_rows($result)) echo "<font color=#008000><Center><b>**Successful Login**</b></Center></font>" 
 **//// I thought maybe this would be the section for the redirection code****
;

else echo "<font color=#ff0000><Center><b>**Failed Login**</b></Center></font>";
 mysql_close();
}
else echo "<font color=#ff8000><Center><b>**No login attempted**</b></Center></font>";

?>
```

Comment: What if the username isn't filled in?

Answer (score 3):

after the check of login do this:

```
header("Location: newPage.php"); // replace newpage with whatever you want
```

**UPDATE**

put the header **BEFORE** any echoing:

```
header("Location: newPage.php"); // replace newpage with whatever you want
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) echo "<font color=#008000><Center><b>**Successful Login**</b></Center></font>"
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the feedback. I've tried inserting and using the header but give me an error on that line after the successful on in. Can you tell me were to exactly put it? Thanks

Comment: Do an "exit()" after the header() command so you don't carry on with further program execution. I'm not sure relative URLs are legal either, even if most browsers accept them, would advise using a fully-qualified URL.

Comment: @James i usually **only** use relative urls, and you might be right about the `exit`

Comment: Hi again. I tried your recommendation but i get this error message'

Comment: @Neal relative URLs might work but are incorrect http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 and I'm right about the `exit()`

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that you don't echo or print anything before, and then you can do:

```
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com");
```

Alternatively, if you want to redirect after having printed stuff, I usually have a function that prints javascript

```
function refresh_to( $location = 'index.php'){
    $output = '<script> window.location.href = '.$location.'; </script>';
    return $output;
}
```

And call it out afterwards.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\Hosting\7616039\html\NHandDesigns\democode\demo-code\hostscripts-12870.inc:25) in D:\Hosting\7616039\html\NHandDesigns\democode\demo-code\getresult.inc on line 19
> ?>

Comment: That's because you already printed content out on the page.  If you use the header() method, it has to be before you display content.

Comment: Put it before the first "echo".  And afterwards, it's good practice and avoids errors to add "exit".

Comment: Thanks i did get a response from your code.     The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /NHandDesigns/democode/demo-code/.$location.

Answer (score 0):

header("Location: /my/new/location");

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me were to insert code, I tried after successful login

Answer (score 0):

```
header("refresh:5;url=http://google.com");
// version 1.1
if ( isset($_POST['password']) ) { // if the password is set then the form has been submitted on login.php page
    include("config.php");
    $username =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $qstr = "SELECT * from members where username ='$username' and password ='$password'";

    $result = mysql_query($qstr);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        $return = "<font color=#008000><Center><b>**Successful Login**</b></Center></font>";
    } else {
        $return = "<font color=#ff0000><Center><b>**Failed Login**</b></Center></font>";
    }
    mysql_close();
} else {
    $return "<font color=#ff8000><Center><b>**No login attempted**</b></Center></font>";
}

// Do the output    
print($return);
```

Remember separate Logic and Output, this will be good practice for your coding.

Notice i use `header` and then do `print`, also in the `header` i put `refresh` 5 (seconds), this will give time for your visitor to read the notice you give (what the point, if you give notice but they didn't have time to read it.)

Comment: Hi Thanks i tried the above code I copied and pasted.    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\Hosting\7616039\html\NHandDesigns\democode\demo-code\hostscripts-12870.inc:25) in D:\Hosting\7616039\html\NHandDesigns\democode\demo-code\getresult.inc on line 22
// Do the output header("refresh:5;url=http://google.com"); print($return);

Comment: @b_rocks: oh sorry just move the header to the top of your code. see the code i edited.

Comment: Hello GusDe. Thanks for your insight. I did move the code to the top and this is what i got.